# Jinja2 join only for lists

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template that takes lists or strings. I know I can use the `join(', ')` filter to separate lists, but where the entry is a single list item, it will separate every character of the string, which is not what I want. How can I tell Jinja2 to only use the filter if it is processing a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should give it only lists if it expects lists. just use `[your_string]` to trasform your string to a list with one item:

```
if not isinstance(lst, (list, tuple)):
    lst = [lst]
```